# Структура хранения информации в реляционной БД

Tags: база-данных, структуры-данных

Есть архитектурное решение узла, отвечающего за регистрацию движений мат. ценностей на складе:

[image: Архитектура узла регистрации движения материальных ценностей]

Поскольку у каждого типа материальных ценностей есть большое кол-во уникальных атрибутов, то было предложено решение о создании таблицы под каждый тип товара, чтобы не громоздить все атрибуты в одну общую таблицу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем данное решение может быть плохим и чем хорошим,
а так же стоит ли его использовать?

**UPDATE**

Т.к. решение, предложенное выше является нарушением многих важных вещей и препятствующий многим другим важным вещям был предложен вариант использующий EAV модель:

[image: EAV модель архитектуры]

Comment: надо не одну таблицу с атрибутами в ширину по столбцам на все товары, а создать таблицу в которой будут перечислены атрибуты и их тип. Затем таблицу связей ценностей и атрибутов. А потом записывать данные в таблицу товар-атрибут-значение.

Comment: 1) Денормализация; 2) Для получения сведений о нескольких типах одновременно нужен либо мультиджойн, либо динамический SQL; 3) Трудно строить систему контроля целостности. === Лучше посмотрите в сторону EAV.

Comment: @teran почему вы уверены, что ваше решение - самое лучшее?

Comment: @PavelMayorov а где-то заявил что оно лучшее? Оно в нормальной форме будет в отличие от варианта в вопросе. Позволит легко расширять перечень атрибутов и товаров, привязывать атрибуты к ним. осуществлять выборки по одинаковым атрибутам для разных типов товаров и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что плохо в вашем решении:

- под каждый новый появившийся товар придется создавать новую таблицу
- под каждую таблицу придется писать свои методы работы с ней. Т.е. вам придется каждый товар обрабатывать своим уникальным SQL-запросом

Как обычно решается подобная задача.

Создается одна(1) дополнительная таблица с полями:

- ID товара
- Тип атрибута
- Значение атрибута

И выборка всех атрибутов любого товара превращается в один запрос:

```
SELECT type, value FROM attributes WHERE id_parent=:id
```

Answer (score 2):

> чем данное решение может быть плохим

Существует мнение, что правильно построенная база данных ни при каких обстоятельствах не должна требовать от клиентского приложения выполнения DDL-кода. Хотя бы из соображений безопасности: могу создать - значит, могу и удалить. В Вашем же случае появление нового типа товара с новым набором атрибутов такого выполнения потребует обязательно - особенно в случае, если ранее какой-либо атрибут с такими характеристиками нигде не встречался.